# Why is my MakeFile path setup getting a "No such file or directory" error?

Tags: tensorflow, makefile, include-path

I am trying to run a makefile. I think the makefile is trying to access this path:

`/home/s/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen`

But when I run it, I get a `No such file or directory` error:

```
(base) s@s-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/3d-psrnet-master$ make
make: Circular utils/tf_ops/cd/tf_nndistance_g.cu <- utils/tf_ops/cd/tf_nndistance_g.cu.o dependency dropped.
/usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin/nvcc  -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++11 -c -o utils/tf_ops/cd/tf_nndistance_g.cu.o utils/tf_ops/cd/tf_nndistance_g.cu -I /home/s/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages -DGOOGLE_CUDA=1 -x cu -Xcompiler -fPIC -O2
utils/tf_ops/cd/tf_nndistance_g.cu:3:10: fatal error: include/unsupported/Eigen: No such file or directory
 #include "include/unsupported/Eigen"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [makefile:12: utils/tf_ops/cd/tf_nndistance_g.cu.o] Error 1
```

I have it set like this at the top of makefile: `tensorflow = /home/s/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages` (which is the path that shows up if I type into Terminal `pip show tensorflow`)

And then in `tf_nndistance_g.cu` I have:

`#include "include/unsupported/Eigen/"`

What might be the reason that this makefile isn't working? I'm using Python 3.7 on a Virtual Machine (ubuntu Virtualbox). Thanks.

Comment: I know nothing really, but perhaps it should be `tensorflow = /home/s/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow`.

Comment: I'm not sure this will help but maybe...let me know if this is way off base and I'll delete this comment.  `--library-path=<path>` https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#file-and-path-specifications

Comment: As @PeterWood said, the `-I` option you specify is wrong, or at least it does not support resolving `#include "include/unsupported/Eigen/"` to `/home/s/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen`.

Comment: Additionally, the trailing slash on `include/unsupported/Eigen/` is suspicious. It is probably at least unnecessary.